# str_replace works with single quote but not double

Tags: php, str-replace

Hi have the following code:

```
$ItemDescriptionNEW = str_replace('\"', '&quot;',$ItemDescription);
$ItemDescriptionNEW = str_replace('\'', '&apos;', $ItemDescriptionNEW);
```

When I execute it, only the single quote get replaced.
I've been looking for the problem for the past hour and can't figure it out...

Comment: There's also [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). In case you were trying to reimplement that.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove the backslash where you use it with the double quote. Because you don't have to escape anything. So just use this:

```
$ItemDescriptionNEW = str_replace('"', '&quot;',$ItemDescription);
```